# how post object include image file into server with axios

Tags: reactjs

i have a form that get image file from user and i want to send this as object to my server but it gives me an empty object in server while the other data such as Name ,about ,.... are exist.
and an object that save in my server like this:

```
{
"id": 1
}
```

and if idon't pass header to axios it gives me an object like this :

```
{
    "UserName": "tom",
    "UserAvatar": {},
    "Specialty": "programmer",
    "Summary": "about ",
    "id": 1
  }
```

My form Codes:

```
const CompleteProfile = () => {
    const [Name, setName] = useState("tom");
    const [Speciality, setSpeciality] = useState("programmer");
    const [ImageFile, setImageFile] = useState(null);
    const [About, setAbout] = useState("about ");
    
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("ImageFile", ImageFile);
        const UserChanges = {
            UserName : Name,
            UserAvatar : formData,
            Specialty: Speciality ,
            Summary: About
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/Image/', UserChanges ,{
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }})
      .then(response =>{
        return response.data} )
      .catch(error => {
          console.error('There was an error!', error.response.data);
      });
    }
    
    return (
                    <div className="mt-8 md:mt-0 col-span-2 flex items-center md:col-span-1">
                        
                        <input class="block w-full text-sm
                         text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg
                          border border-gray-300 cursor-pointer
                           dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none
                            dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600
                             dark:placeholder-gray-400"
                            type="file"
                            id="file"
                            onChange={(e)=> setImageFile(e.target.files[0])}
                             />
                        
                    <button
                        className='bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700
                          text-white 
                        w-fit p-3 rounded-3xl
                        hover:rounded-full
                        
                        '
                        onClick={handleSubmit}
                        >
                        save                    </button>

                </div>



             )
}

export default CompleteProfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass all your data in the form data, and then actually pass the form data to the API with `axios` like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("UserName", Name);
formData.append("UserAvatar", ImageFile);
formData.append("Specialty", Speciality);
formData.append("Summary", About);
axios
  .post("http://localhost:8000/Image/", formData)
```

Comment: i used your code but it gives me an object with id and doesn't give me the formData

Comment: try now, I've made an edit

Comment: nothing happend is the same result

Comment: check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hoover-6xf3u2?file=/src/App.js) codesandbox, check the network tab. the request won't succeed obviously, but the formdata is being passed. it might be an issue with your backend code.